# Creating a new folder with extension and current date

Tags: r, directory

I was wondering if someone has an idea if it is possible to create a new folder within R and write the current date automatically to it, e.g. New Folder: "TEST_20140903"? Is this possible?

What I am attempting to do is to move my output (several thousands plots) into a new folder and then each time I am running the script the current date should be written in the extension.

Comment: You mean something like `dir.create(paste("Test", Sys.Date(), sep = "_"))`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make use of `dir.create` in conjunction with `paste` and `Sys.Date`, like this:

```
dir.create(paste("Test", Sys.Date(), sep = "_"))
```

If you want to change into that directory, I would suggest storing the output of `paste` as a character vector and using `setwd` after creating the new directory.

Demo:

```
x <- getwd()  ## I'm going to demo in a tempdir
setwd(tempdir())
list.dirs()
# [1] "."                                                 
# [2] "./downloaded_packages"                             
# [3] "./rs-graphics-16e13b20-59b3-4ef3-bdcd-02852b1ea576"
newdir <- paste("Test", Sys.Date(), sep = "_")
dir.create(newdir)
setwd(newdir)
list.dirs()
# [1] "."                                                 
# [2] "./downloaded_packages"                             
# [3] "./rs-graphics-16e13b20-59b3-4ef3-bdcd-02852b1ea576"
# [4] "./Test_2014-09-03"                                 
setwd(x)     ## Reset to original working directory
```

---

You could always create a function like the following, but be careful of recursion!

```
Today <- function(prefix = "Test") {
  newdir <- paste(prefix, Sys.Date(), sep = "_")
  dir.create(newdir)
  setwd(newdir)
}
```

This could be called simply with `Today()` and would create the necessary directory in whatever directory you're currently in and set your working directory to that new directory.

Comment: while at it, is there a way I could set my working directory automatically to this newly created folder?

Comment: @redshoe, I've updated--does that help? (It's not automatic.)

Comment: thank you. this is great! Is there a way I could also change it without getting in a temp directory. My initial wd is Users/xyz/Desktop and I'm creating the folder with current date using create.dir, then I would like to change to this created folder

Comment: @redshoe, the changing into a `tempdir` is just for demonstration purposes.

Comment: Thank you very much for the edit with the Today function. This works perfectly with what I was attempting to do!

Comment: @redshoe, I would suggest looking at `.First` and `.Last` so that the function can be called automatically on starting a new session and the working directory can be reset automatically at the end of the session.